# Checking if string in column contain word

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Could you help me with one task? I know that is very easy, but can't understand how it do.

For example, I have df with 2 columns:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
        "url": ["https://mob.bla.com", "https://bla-bla.com", 
              "https://mob.test.ru"],
        "info": ["travel", "humor", "news"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

And I want to find url and info about url if only url contain "mob".

Comment: df[df.url.str.contains('mob')]